# why everyone is not answering if there is no bounty?

Tags: support, answers

I asked question and waited for 1 week.At last I lost my patience and place a bounty on it .Finally I got an answer .So my question is why it took long time to answer if community really knows an answer ,are they are waiting for me to place bounty?

Comment: If you make [reasonable] edits to your post then it will come up top in active posts. That will also draw attention. Many users [like me] see "active" tab instead of "new" tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users are not expecting you to offer a bounty. **It is user's choice**. They will answer when they find the answer to your question and when they want to write an answer.

It is users' choice when to answer. So, post the question and sit back and relax. You may get an answer at any time. There are **[hundreds of questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)** which have no answers yet. it is too quick to expect an answer a question. If you want an answer immediately, place a bounty. It is your choice.